# Cannot set launcher label independently of main activity label

Tags: android, android-intent

So I've seen this asked a few times and usually the answer is that a label hasn't been given to the intent filter. However:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >

        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

title_activity_main is still being displayed in the launcher rather than app_name.

What small thing am I not seeing here?

Thanks :)

Comment: android:label="@string/title_activity_main" change this

Comment: @Triode If I change it, the launcher label DOES change... But then so too does the label in the actionbar

Comment: Make the change, so the two strings are different, then reboot the device or emulator. Or, do a full uninstall and reinstall of the app after making the change. It may be that your home screen is caching information and is not noticing the altered resource.

Comment: @CommonsWare This is what I thought too. But no luck, it seems that the launcher is flat ignoring the presence of android:label on the intent-filter.

Answer (score 0):

So eventually... After blitzing my ENTIRE environment, reinstalling studio and a new emulator. It worked as documented

EDIT: Also had to blow away the entire SDK